# How to remove the shadow below the center point?

Tags: java, android, teechart

I have styled my `CircularGauge` a bit like they did here:
[Circular Gauge Gradient - TeeChart - MonoAndroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864398/circular-gauge-gradient-teechart-monoandroid)

[image]

How can I remove the shadow below the center point? And while I'm at it, how can I change the color of the pointer (indicator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below the code I got after translating [Narcís's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12893458/509369):

```
    tChart1.getHeader().setVisible(false);

    CircularGauge circularGauge1 = new CircularGauge(tChart1.getChart());

    circularGauge1.getFrame().setVisible(false);
    circularGauge1.getFaceBrush().setVisible(false);
    circularGauge1.setDisplayTotalAngle(180);
    circularGauge1.setTotalAngle(180);
    circularGauge1.setValue(200);
    circularGauge1.getTicks().setVisible(false);
    circularGauge1.setMinimum(0);
    circularGauge1.setMaximum(1000);
    circularGauge1.getAxis().getAxisPen().setVisible(false);
    circularGauge1.getAxis().setIncrement(500);
    circularGauge1.getRedLine().setVisible(false);
    circularGauge1.setGreenLineStartValue(0);
    circularGauge1.setGreenLineEndValue(1000);
    circularGauge1.getGreenLine().getGradient().setDirection(GradientDirection.HORIZONTAL);
    circularGauge1.getGreenLine().getGradient().setUseMiddle(true);
    circularGauge1.getGreenLine().getGradient().setStartColor(Color.orange);
    circularGauge1.getGreenLine().getGradient().setMiddleColor(Color.yellow);
    circularGauge1.getGreenLine().getGradient().setEndColor(Color.green);
    circularGauge1.getGreenLine().getPen().setVisible(false);
```

This is how it looks for me:

[image: CircularGauge]

Comment: Hiding the frame was the key. Thanks.