# Left axis label font reset to red color?

Tags: java, android, teechart

Please recall this code:
[How to remove the shadow below the center point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928039/how-to-remove-the-shadow-below-the-center-point)

When I display that chart and later switch to a bar/pie chart, the left axis label is set to **red**. I cannot understand this as I never modify that variable. I'm sure this is a bug.

A workaround is to set the color explicitly before I generate the diagram:

```
_chart.getAxes().getLeft().getLabels().getFont().setColor(Color.fromArgb(0xffffffff));
```

Also, relevant function calls may be the following:

```
_chart.setAutoRepaint(false);
_chart.removeAllSeries();
_chart.getAxes().getBottom().setIncrement(1);
```

Comment: If you're sure this is a bug, then this is probably not the correct place to 'report' it. I recommend you rephrase your question into an actual question.

Comment: Good point. Well, I _sense_ a bug :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. When the CircularGauge is disposed, the chart axis is restoring wrong default Ticks&MinorTicks pens and Labels font. I've just corrected it for the next maintenance release.